# Mouth problem and bloody patches

Tags: cats

my cat is opening her mouth  and putting her paws to her jaw like she's trying to expell somthing from the back of her throat. Also she is losing patches of hair with scabs and blood attached to them. No vomitting, eating normally.

Comment: Take her to the vet as soon as possible. You need medical advice on this problem. If you can get a video of her doing the open mouth/put paws on jaw thing, that may be helpful to show the vet. Good luck to you and your cat.

Comment: Yes, anything involving blood in abnormal places needs a vet. We can't diagnose or cure her here, only offer advice.

Comment: Note that this applies to other animals too, Including humans -- if anything is bleeding that shouldn't, or more than it should,  go straight to a doctor, NOT the internet.

Answer (score 1):

The sort of things you are describing are due to some sort of health problem.

Would you allow you child to have the same problems without taking them to a doctor? Of course you would not.

Take her to a vet and have here checked over.

SimonT